# two dimension array with assoc and for loop php

Tags: php

I write that code but i got error

```
    $tablica = [
'xd'=>['jabłka', 'wiśnie', 'gruszki'],
'xd'=>['jabłska', 'wisssśnie', 'grussssszki']
];
$n=count($tablica);
echo "<table border=1>";
for($i = 0; $i <count($tablica); ++$i) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for($x = 0; $x < count($tablica[$i]); $x++){
        echo "<td>".$tablica[$i][$x]."</td><br>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

it's simple but when i add assoc for 1st dimension it's broke with that error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp64\www\projects\xd\1.php on line 10

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\projects\xd\1.php on line 10
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with using `for()` loops, then the problem is that your array has `xd` and `xd1` as the keys, but your trying to access them with `$i` which is `0` and `1`.  What you can do is create an array of the keys (I've set `$keys` using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)) and then index that using `$keys[$i]`...

```
$tablica = [
    'xd'=>['jabłka', 'wiśnie', 'gruszki'],
    'xd1'=>['jabłska', 'wisssśnie', 'grussssszki']
];

$n=count($tablica);
$keys = array_keys($tablica);
echo "<table border=1>";
for($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for($x = 0; $x < count($tablica[$keys[$i]]); $x++){
        echo "<td>".$tablica[$keys[$i]][$x]."</td><br>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding complexity when there is no need to.
When using associative arrays, `foreach` is usually a best way to iterate.
You can replace your code with:

```
$tablica = [
    'xd'=>['jabłka', 'wiśnie', 'gruszki'],
    'xd'=>['jabłska', 'wisssśnie', 'grussssszki']
];

echo "<table border=1>";
foreach($tablica as $tr) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($tr as $td) {
        echo "<td>".$td."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

PS: you have duplicated key named `xd`. Then PHP will only get the last one.